# Can't delete a document from Mongodb via Express route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I want to delete a Mongodb document by id, passing it to Express route.

In the console, I receive a message that says it is deleted.

```
GET /api/videolinks 304 94.792 ms - -
Removed id= 562b905f633288ac0d8b4567
DELETE /api/videolinks/562b905f633288ac0d8b4567 200 68.550 ms - 19743
```

But it is not.

```
> db.hyperlinks.find({"_id": ObjectId("562b905f633288ac0d8b4567")})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("562b905f633288ac0d8b4567"), "file" : "http://storage.akamai.com/get/b113/p/coub/simple/cw_file/79632d71313/9aedca2cd4d3094e75834/iphone_hellosergii_iphone.mp4" }
```

My Angularjs factory:

```
/*global angular*/
angular.module('myService', [])

    // each function returns a promise object 
    .factory('Videolinks', ['$http',function($http) {
        return {
            get : function() {
                return $http.get('/api/videolinks');
            },
            delete : function(id) {
                return $http.delete('/api/videolinks/' + id);
            }
        };
    }]);
```

My route.js

```
var path = require('path');
var Videolink = require('./models/mydb');

var mongodb = require('mongodb');

// Get links
function getLinks(res){
  Videolink.find(function(err, hyperlinks) {
    // if there is an error retrieving, send the error. nothing after res.send(err) will execute
    if (err) {
        res.send(err);
    }

    res.json(hyperlinks); // return all videos in JSON format
  });
}

module.exports = function(app) {

    // api ---------------------------------------------------------------------

  // use mongoose to get all videos in the database
    app.get('/api/videolinks', function(req, res) {
        getLinks(res);
    });

    // delete a video
    app.delete('/api/videolinks/:video_id', function(req, res) {
        Videolink.remove({
            _id : mongodb.ObjectID(req.params.video_id)
        }, function(err) {

            if (err) {
                res.send(err);
            }
            console.log("Removed id= " + req.params.video_id);

            getLinks(res);
        });
    });


    // application -------------------------------------------------------------
    app.get('*', function(res) {
        res.sendFile('index.html', {root: path.join(__dirname, './public')}); // load the single view file 
    });
};
```

The `app.get` functionality works pretty well here.
What could be wrong with `app.delete`?

Here is my DB schema in `models/mydb`

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var db_schema = new Schema({
  //text: String
  _id: String,
  source: String,
  orig_page: String,
  likes: Number,
  title: String,
  file: String,
  video_mobile_res: String,
  video_high_res_mutes_muted: String,
  audio_high_res: String,
  video_med_res_muted: String,
  audio_med_res: String
}, {collection: 'hyperlinks'});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Videolink', db_schema);
```

Comment: Just you logged that it was deleted to the console doesn't make it so.  Are you using mongoose?

Comment: Yes, I use mongoose.

Comment: Are you using any sort of proxy for the app.  I know the delete verb is sometimes not enabled as a valid verb, and needs to be allowed.

Comment: @RobertMoskal, I updated my question with DB schema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your particular problem is that you defined the _id field as a String in your schema:

```
var db_schema = new Schema({
   _id: String,
   ...
```

Take that out and your code should work fine.  You may have even uncovered a mongoose bug, since you are supposed to be able to specify the _id field type. Maybe some mongoose expert can tell us more.

Comment: I changed to `Videolink.remove({_id : req.params.video_id}...` but it didn't help.

Comment: Command `db.hyperlinks.find({"_id": ObjectId("562b905f633288ac0d8b4567")})` returns the document. And `db.hyperlinks.find({"_id": "562b905f633288ac0d8b4567"})` gives no result. Seems id is an object after all.

Comment: Take out the _id:String in the schema cosntructor.  See whether that fixes it. Then you might try findByIdAndRemove which should be able to coerce the string.

Comment: I deleted `_id: String` from the DB schema. And now it works, the document deleted. Thank you.

Comment: I've never seen the _id field type specified.  It must introduce this strange behavior. I'll update my answer it might help someone else.